# click through span

Tags: jquery

I have a span tag that's over an input field. What I'm trying to do is when you click on the input field the span with text in it gets hidden. then on Blur it's shown. This all works using jquery. The problem is because the span is on top of the input field the input focus doesn't get triggered when you click on the span text. Is there a way to get around this and not have the span stop the input filed focus from working.

Comment: please show the html you are using

Comment: It is helpful if you can provide a code example to illustrate your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the focus on the input if the span is clicked.

```
$('#span').click(function() {

     $('#input').focus();

});

$('#input').focus(function() {

     $('#span').hide();

});

$('#input').blur(function() {

     $('#span').show();

});
```

Comment: Is there a way to detect if auto fill has happened on a input field. I don't see any events that work for this.

Comment: Not in jQuery itself, but there are plugins. Use Google for that. ;)

Comment: @Chapsterj that sounds like a different question to me.

Comment: The problem with using code like this is that you're not caching selectors, causing unnecessary slowness in Javascript. See my answer for an example of what caching selectors looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is your code...

```
<span id="span">Some text to hide</span>
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

Your Javascript would look something like this:

```
var span = $('#span'),
    input = $('#input');

input.focus(function() {
    span.hide();
}).blur(function() {
    span.show();
});

span.click(function() {
    input.focus();
});
```